# Scrapy FormRequest parameter not working but showing all result instead

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this webpage https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/advanced-search/?keyword=&source=sharepoint&type=project&status=open&_pp_projectstatus=&_pp_hiname=&_pp_piname=&_pp_source=sharepoint&_pp_details=#project using Scrapy FormRequest. My code is as below. The parameter `_pp_hiname` with `ab` and `_pp_piname` with `pua` should only return 1 result in `response.text` but instead it returns all the result in HTML code. Parameter apparently not working but I couldn't see any wrong with it.

```
def start_requests(self):
    params = {
        'keyword': '',
        'source': 'sharepoint',
        'type': 'project',
        'status': 'open',
        'page': '1',
        '_pp_projectstatus': '',
        '_pp_hiname': 'ab',
        '_pp_piname': 'pua',
        '_pp_source': '',
        '_pp_details': '',
        'name':'advancesearchawardedprojectsp'
    }
    yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid',callback=self.parse_item,method='POST',formdata=params,headers = {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'})

def parse_item(self,response):
    print(response.text)
```

Should be only 1 entry:
[image: actual result]

But apparently it is showing all entry:
[image: shows all result]

**Latest update:**

```
class ToScrapeCSSSpiderSG(scrapy.Spider):
name = "toscrapesg-css"
# start_urls = [
    # 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid',
# ] 
params = {
    'name':'advancesearchawardedprojectsp'
    }  
args = {
        'keyword': '',
        'source': 'sharepoint',
        'type': 'project',
        'status': 'open',
        'page': 1,
        '_pp_projectstatus': '',
        '_pp_hiname': 'ab',
        '_pp_piname': '',
        '_pp_source': '',
        '_pp_details': '',
        'name':'advancesearchawardedprojectsp'
    }
def start_requests(self):
    args = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.args)
    url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,callback=self.parse_item,method='POST',formdata=self.params,headers = {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'})


def parse_item(self,response):
    args = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.args)
    url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args
    for quote in response.xpath('//div[contains(@style,"overflow-x:auto")]'):
        for row in quote.xpath('./table[contains(@class,"table-striped")]/tbody/tr'):
            link=row.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(link,callback = self.parse_product,method='GET')


    onclick = response.xpath('//a[@aria-label="Next page"]/@onclick').get()
    if onclick:
        self.args['page'] += 1
        args = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.args)
        url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_item, method='POST', formdata=self.params, headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

def parse_product(self,response):
        text = response.xpath('//span[contains(@id,"ctl00_ctl47_g_b43c0a74_fae0_498f_b75e_c103772db011_ctl00_lblProjectTitle")]/text()').extract()
        # text = info.xpath('./text()').extract()
        print(text)
```

**Console message:**
[image]

Comment: normally form on page reload full page - and you get this. Page may reload only part of code only if it uses JavaScript by Scrapy can't run JavaScript.

Comment: in browser I see it send as POST only `Name=advancesearchawardedprojectsp`. Rest is send as arguments in URL - you send all in POST body - and it makes difference.

Comment: nice and clear explanation bro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sends in `POST` body only `Name=advancesearchawardedprojectsp`. Other parameters should be in url as query.

So `url` should be

https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?keyword=&source=sharepoint&type=project&status=open&page=1&_pp_projectstatus=&_pp_hiname=ab&_pp_piname=pua&_pp_source=&_pp_details

You can use `urllib.parse.urlencode(args)` for this.

And it gives me one result.

```
import urllib.parse

def start_requests(self):

    params = {
        'name':'advancesearchawardedprojectsp'
    }

    args = {
        'keyword': '',
        'source': 'sharepoint',
        'type': 'project',
        'status': 'open',
        'page': '1',
        '_pp_projectstatus': '',
        '_pp_hiname': 'ab',
        '_pp_piname': 'pua',
        '_pp_source': '',
        '_pp_details': '',
    }

    args = urllib.parse.urlencode(args)

    url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args

    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_item,method='POST',formdata=params,headers = {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'})
```

---

**EDIT:** example which loads next pages and check button `Next Page` to stop.

**EDIT:** now it can save in `csv` file.

```
import scrapy
import urllib.parse

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'
    #allowed_domains = []

    params = {
        'name': 'advancesearchawardedprojectsp'
    }

    args = {
        'keyword': '',
        'source': 'sharepoint',
        'type': 'project',
        'status': 'open',
        'page': 1,
        '_pp_projectstatus': '',

        #'_pp_hiname': 'tan',
        #'_pp_piname': '',
        '_pp_hiname': 'ab',
        '_pp_piname': '', #'pua',

        '_pp_source': '',
        '_pp_details': '',
    }

    def start_requests(self):

        # create request for first page
        args = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.args)

        url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_item, method='POST', formdata=self.params, headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})


    def parse_item(self,response):
        #print('parse_item] url:', response.url)
        #print('parse_item] text:', response.text)

        #for quote in response.xpath('//div[contains(@style,"overflow-x:auto")]'):
        #    for row in quote.xpath('./table[contains(@class,"table-striped")]/tbody/tr'):
        #        link = row.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract_first()
        #        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_product)

        for row in response.xpath('//table[@name="MVCGridTable_advancesearchawardedprojectsp"]/tbody/tr'):
            link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            #title = row.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_product)

        # create request for next page
        onclick = response.xpath('//a[@aria-label="Next page"]/@onclick').get()

        if onclick:
            # next page 
            self.args['page'] += 1
            args = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.args)
            url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_item, method='POST', formdata=self.params, headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

    def parse_product(self, response):
        #print('parse_product] url:', response.url)

        # .extract_first() or .get() instead of .extract()
        project_id = response.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl47_g_b43c0a74_fae0_498f_b75e_c103772db011_ctl00_lblProjIdExt"]/text()').get()
        title = response.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl47_g_b43c0a74_fae0_498f_b75e_c103772db011_ctl00_lblProjectTitle"]/text()').get()
        pi = response.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl47_g_b43c0a74_fae0_498f_b75e_c103772db011_ctl00_lblLeadPIName"]/text()').get()
        hi = response.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl47_g_b43c0a74_fae0_498f_b75e_c103772db011_ctl00_lblHostInstName"]/text()').get()
        date = response.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl47_g_b43c0a74_fae0_498f_b75e_c103772db011_ctl00_dtPickerStartDate"]/text()').get()
        # etc.

        item = {
            'id': project_id,
            'title': title,
            'pi': pi,
            'hi': hi,
            'date': date,
        }

        yield item

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204090/discussion-on-answer-by-furas-scrapy-formrequest-parameter-not-working-but-showi).

Comment: thanks man for helping all the way man! finally kinda got the whole thing right!